# Gradle how to add multiple includes without error

Tags: gradle, ant

When I put multiple includes it gives me an error prompt. Also having trouble with calling my property from gradle.properties with out no error.

```
ant.path(id: 'cobertura.classpath.id') {
    //resource ('tasks.properties')
    fileset(dir: project.'cobertura.dir', includes: 'cobertura-2.1.1.jar', includes: 'lib/**/*.jar')
    fileset(dir: project.'junit.dir', includes: 'junit-4.8.2.jar')
}

ant.path(id: 'classpath') {
    ant.pathelement (path: 'dist/classes')
    fileset(dir: project.'hdm.dir', includes: '**/*.jar')
    fileset(dir: project.'dozer.dir', includes: '*.jar')
    fileset(dir: project.'commons-lang3.dir', includes: '*.jar')
    fileset(dir: project.'spring-integration.dir', includes: 'spring-integration-core' + '-' + project.'spring-integration.version' + '.jar'
            includes: 'spring-integration-stream-' + project.'spring-integration.version' + '.jar'
            includes: 'spring-integration-jms-' + project.'spring-integration.version' + '.jar')
}
```

**Problem Prompt**
[image: Command Line img of error]

Comment: `includes` should be _comma- or space-separated list of patterns of files that must be included; all files are included when omitted._. Have you tried it?

Comment: When I separated it with a comma, It prompts me "The <fileset> type doesn't support nested text data ("*.jar">

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you Opal.
Fixed:
instead of --
includes: 'cobertura-2.1.1.jar', includes: 'lib/**/*.jar')

Do This:
includes: 'cobertura-2.1.1.jar, includes: 'lib/**/*.jar')

Comment: But I am still stuck on the fileset with id 'classpath' with the multiple includes.